# PHP - How to get custom customer attribute

Tags: php, customer-attribute

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i have installed this module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes.html

I've created attribute with attribute code `sms_promo`

My question is how can i select this attribute information in PHP ?

Comment: what you mean by select?

Comment: Something like this: `$customer->getResource()->getAttribute('sms_promo')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);`

Comment: can you please show your code as `$customer->getResource()->getAttribute('sms_promo')->getFrontend()->getValue($c‌​ustomer); ` is ok